# Regex Expression Not Working From Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I have a Regex expression which is working at https://regex101.com/r/gX8fB6/1

When I run from Blueprism it doesn't find any matches.

Regex:

```
(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\-\d{2}
```

String:

Membership no: 1234567800; 
Member name: Jane Doe; 
Group ID: 12345; 
Staff no: ; 
Cancel date: 17-JUN-22;
Cancel reason: Member Leaves;

Comment: Replace `\d` with `[0-9]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Tried: (([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\-[0-9]{2}

Comment: Did you use it like [here](https://regex101.com/r/U2J2ib/2)?

Comment: Yes works there but not from Blueprism (it just finds 0 matches)

Comment: What if you use non-capturing groups? `(?:[0-9]|[0-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])-(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]{2}`. It may be related to other Blueprism options.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the same thing

Comment: Then it is a Blueprism thing, not related to regex.